# Meaning of <?rb ...?> tag

Tags: html, unicode, tags

I have found a tag that I've never seen before:

```
<?rb　#デバッグ用 ?>
```

In general, how do browsers handle `<? ?>` tags, and what are they used for?

Comment: The only place on that site where I see `<?rb　#デバッグ用 ?>` is in a HTML comment `<!--<?rb　#デバッグ用 ?>-->`. HTML comments can have anything in between them: `<!-- blah anything can goe here -->`

Answer (score 2):

`rb` is used for ruby annotation (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rb). This seems compatible (and used) with Japanese language.

`<?` is a common pre-processor prefix (e.g. php). To me it seems just a source code of some Japanese text that will be transformed to HTML (so it is not yet full HTML code). This could be very handy to have less text (and so easy to read from source).

A short Google search (but somewhat difficult because of symbols), it seems that some asciidoc and similar use such extension: `<?rb ...>` to incorporate Ruby code.

So if you find other `<?rb ...>` with actual code, I would say it is ruby code (`#` is just comment), used to check some characteristics of text. If it has only Japanese text, I would check if it can be interpreted as ruby annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the HTML Specification by W3, it seems to skip the content in between `<? and >`

https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#comments

The data within the `<? >` tags might be for server side processing

> A sequence of bytes starting with: 0x3C 0x3F (ASCII `'<?'`)
>
> Advance the position pointer so that it points at the first 0x3E byte (ASCII >) that comes after the 0x3C (ASCII <) byte that was found.